# UISegmentedControl messed up after customization

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

So after I customize the UISegmentedControl, everything got messed up, the label got shifted and there is a white vertical line which I don't know where it came from. The divider also got off-center, I have checked that the black line is at 40-41px of a 80px image, so it must be centered. Want am I doing wrong or have anybody experience this before?

**Before Customization:**
[image]

**After Customization:**

note: the divider images is a horizontal flip of each other.

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
UIImage *un_sel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"divider-un-sel"];
UIImage *sel_un = [UIImage imageNamed:@"divider-sel-un"];

[_segmentControl setDividerImage:un_sel forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[_segmentControl setDividerImage:sel_un forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

UIImage *normal = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment-normal"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:0];
UIImage *selected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment-selected"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:20 topCapHeight:0];

[_segmentControl setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[_segmentControl setBackgroundImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by using

```
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"segment-normal"]  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
```

instead of `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWith:topCapHeight`